# jQuery scroll to a section in another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to create a new script with the jQuery library to scroll to a specific id on a page but I have two problems:

1. I can't delete the `href` content in the address bar. For example, my link scrolls to a section block with the id `anchor-link-section` and in my link I have `href = "index.php#anchor-link-section"`. However, in my address bar I see `www.site.com/index.php#anchor-link-section...`. How can I take it off?
2. If I'm already on the page where my id is `section-scroll`, and my `href` is `href="index.php#section-scroll"`, the page does not scroll, it reloads, to put `www.site.com/index.php#section-scroll` in my address bar, and then scroll to my id

I am using jQuery 3.3.1 and jQuery UI 1.12.0.
I use a url rewriting technology (ex: www.site.com/index)

I have already tried the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('html, body').hide();

    if (window.location.hash) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('html, body').scrollTop(0).show();
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top
                }, 1000)
        }, 0);
    }
    else {
        $('html, body').show();
    }
});
```

I don't have a scroll animation, I can't scroll to an id from on a page without having to modify my address bar...

### Edit

I updated my code as per suggested by jom:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('html, body').hide();

  if $(window.location.hash'a[href$="index#lien-ancre-commu"]') {
    setTimeout.click(function (e) { 

      $('html, body').scrollTop(0) e.showpreventDefault(); 

        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(window.locationthis.hash).offset().top
      }, 1000)
    }, 01000);
  } else {
    $('html, body').show();
  })
});
```

But now I no longer have scroll animation but the switch between pages works.

Nav menu code html :

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="">Accueil</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="/index.php#lien-ancre-commu">Communauté</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="/index.php#lien-ancre-contact">Contact</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="commu">Médias</a>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown"><a class="fas fa-angle-down" data-toggle="dropdown">Plus</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <a href="commu">Admin</a>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: If the href is `index.php#section-scroll` instead of just `#section-scroll`, it will cause the page to reload.

Comment: How can I fix this? @Terry ?

Comment: For number 1 in `delete the href content in the address bar`, by "href content" do you mean to remove the `hash` part of the URL in the address bar?

Comment: Yes that's right I want to remove the id in the url (ex www.site.com/index[#id] <- delete that).                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                 because when I click on an anchor link it puts it in my navigation bar when I don't want to ... @jom

Comment: You really shouldn't remove that. It allows users to link to specific portions of your page. You're removing familiar and expected user-friendliness for the sake of a neater URL.

Answer (score 1):

A simple [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) should do the trick. By doing this, you won't have to deal with removing the hash part of the URL in address bar — it simply will never get appended in there.

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {

  if (window.location.hash) {
    scrollToSection(window.location.hash);
  }

});

$('a[href$="#lien-ancre-commu"]').click(function (e) {
  // Tells the browser not to mess with our links or anchor tags
  e.preventDefault();

  // Because we are redefining how it should behave...
  if (this.pathname === window.location.pathname) {
    // ...that is to scroll to a section of the page
    // IF we are on the intended page
    scrollToSection(this.hash);
  }
  else {
    // Otherwise, redirect them to the page
    window.location.replace(this.href);
  }
});

function scrollToSection(id) {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(id).offset().top
  }, 1000);
}
```

And with all those in place, you will have your links/anchor tags in the following format:

```
<a href="/index.php#lien-ancre-commu">Scroll to section</a>
```

Notice the forward slash character (`/`), we will need this because adding it means we are redirecting to a URL **relative to our application base path** instead of another routes relative to current path.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186613/discussion-on-answer-by-jom-jquery-scroll-to-a-section-in-another-page). (both of you have access to post in this room)

Comment: @jom please can you help me ?

Comment: @BelroDe I'd like to, but I'm not entirely sure why you're getting different results... Or how you really are trying to navigate to pages. It's not clear to me, maybe review our chat history.

Comment: @jom if you are on this page: https://501eme.wixsite.com/accueil/agenda and you go to the navigation menu and click on the link with the name "501st". The page reloads and scrolls to the section "About us".    But if you are on the page with the "scroll" id and you click on the 501st link, the page does not reload like the first example, the scroll action is directly performed


And of course, in the search bar, there is no change to the basic url address.  (501eme.wixsite.com/accueil does not become 501eme.wixsite.com/accueil#id)


Do you understand what I'm trying to do now?

Comment: Well, I tried it on mobile device and the scrolling seemed to work for me for both cases. Wait, why do you want the page to reload again when it's already on the same page? Shouldn't we scroll right to the section instead?